# PlugPlay Service Using CPU In Spikes

Tags: windows, service

I have a couple servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 and I notice that after a couple days of uptime several of them begin experiencing CPU spiked caused by the PlugPlay service.

I thought this could be the result of a couple of storage related scripts I run with task scheduler, so I disabled them and restarted the servers but several days later the problem resumes.

These are the spikes I am seeing in Resource Monitor on one of the servers.

[image: Plug and Play service CPU usage]

It's a pretty beefy Xeon server, and there are smaller servers on which I notice smaller spikes.

Does anyone know a good starting point for tracking down the root of the problem and fixing it?

Comment: I would start with procmon and/or taskmon, but I have no idea hwo to find the exact driver (which is a guess, 99% of such spikes are driver-made, mostly from printers).